# Can IRS call center employees access a person's record without authorization?

Tags: united-states, irs

Let's say I called the IRS two months ago because I had a question. I give the IRS *call center* employee my SS# and other information to identify myself. I assume he/she then accesses my IRS record, I ask him my question, and I hang up.

If this IRS employee saved all the information I gave him in that call two months ago, is it possible that he can go back to my file without my authorization?

Comment: Legally?  No.  Practically?  Yes.  (I'm a DBA, and so have God-like power over all my databases.  Were I so inclined, when I worked on a toll road system, I could have tracked someone all over NJ and southern NY.)

Answer (score 1):

In the 1990's several IRS employees got in trouble because the looked at the tax files of famous people to see how much they made. The employees didn't know the system kept track of everybody who accessed taxpayer files.

In the decades since the 1990's the requirements to track access and look for privacy violations has increased. I am sure the standard training now makes clear that accessing files they shouldn't could lead to loss of job, or even jail time.

The system should link the accessing of files to a specific case, and flag unusual access. Identifying insider threats are a concern many organizations are focusing on.